# Need a Push in the right Direction

Tags: 2d, browser-based-games, web

I know this been asked a millions of time.

First off my Dabbled in a few languages,like Java,C#,Android,Python and unity even though that's not really a language.My Programming is Level as at far below Amateur.

I been conflicted and a bit confused on what to choose.I know there is no Perfect Language.

So here is what i need help with "LONG TERM GOAL"

Web Game/Program
2d Graphics Simple/Pixel
Interactive like a chat room/mmo
Compatible with most Browsers

Now I need help what to really invest months to years into learning.
Do i learn Unity,Flash or something Else.
What do the expert suggest i go with.What ever it is I wanna learn with a full focus.
I am all over the place and its leading me to be a Jack of Nothing.

I Also realize i am not making games for long time i start with hello world and simple chat room or make a simple tic-tac-toe game.I need step 1 rather then then starting at step 234.

Thank you for any Guidance Much Appreciated.

Comment: This sort of question isn't well suited for StackExchange's Q&A style. Please read what StackExchange is all [About](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a professional, but I started right where you are.

First off, it really doesn't matter what language you choose, just pick one and stick with it. If you've been programming for a while, and you understand the core concepts, you should be able to switch between languages relatively quickly.

Once you understand core concepts of programming, learn core of game design. Learn theory, and teach yourself the language dependent parts separately. The language independent parts are MUCH more important. Once you've created some basic games in the language you've chosen (I suggest doing ALL of these: http://lazyfoo.net/articles/article01/index.php) you should nail down what you want, pick a language, pick libraries/tools, and start learning all the quirks of those.

For example: You want to make a web game. If by that you mean a game that will be embedded in a web page, I'd say pick Java or Unity.

Most professional games are written in C/C++, but they are doing something VERY different that from what you want.

If that is indeed what you want long term, start learning that. Every language CAN do what you want, you just need to stick to one for a while.

In summary:
1. Pick a language and learn it.
2. Learn basic game architecture and how to apply it to your chosen language.
3. Make and finish games.
   - This is important to do early on. Its encouraging.
4. Begin work on your project.

Hope this helps,
Best,
Peter